# How to create a rule for outlook 2016 when I am in the bcc field?

Tags: outlook

My outlook at work was recently upgraded. I believe it is 2016 version.
How do I create a rule to highlight emails in which I am a bcc recipient?

I see rules for me being in the To field or the CC field, but not the BCC field.

An old forum post mentioned creating a rule for times when I am NOT in either To or CC, but it does not appear this rule for 'except' scenarios exists in outlook 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCC list is never visible on incoming messages (by definition - "B" in BCC stands for "blind"). And Outlook does not know if one of the To or CC recipients is really you - it is possible you received the message from a POP3/SMTP account or it was sent to an old address that is no longer valid.